# Função na linguagem M (power BI) para trabalhar com horas úteis

Tags: powerbi, powerquery

Boa tarde pessoal!

Preciso de uma função em linguagem m para verificar se o atendimento de um chamado foi feito Dentro ou fora do Prazo.
Para isso eu utilizo os campos "data da resolução" - "data de abertura", mas preciso contabilizar somente horas úteis, de 8:00 às 17:00

Agradeço muito se puderem me ajudar!!

Abraços.